# Window form cannot display from second control

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

I am trying to add a custom control at runtime. So i created a custom control with its own paint method. Whenever the "Add" button clicked, a new control is created and added to main form. But While adding controls,I cannot see others, but first control only. I have no idea about what is happening, Can anyone help?. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
public ref class CustomLine : public UserControl
{
private:
    Point P1,P2;
    Pen ^pen;
public:
    CustomLine(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        P1 = p1;
        P2 = p2;
        pen = gcnew Pen(Color::Red,2);
    }
protected:
    virtual void OnPaint(System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs ^e) override
    {
        e->Graphics->DrawLine(pen,P1,P2);
    }
};


private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
         {
             int xx1 = Convert::ToInt32(this->x1->Text);
             int yy1 = Convert::ToInt32(this->y1->Text);
             int xx2 = Convert::ToInt32(this->x2->Text);
             int yy2 = Convert::ToInt32(this->y2->Text);
             CustomLine ^cline = gcnew CustomLine(Point(xx1,yy1),Point(xx2,yy2));
             this->Controls->Add(cline);
             this->Invalidate();
         }
```

Comment: Your control doesn't have a location and size...

Comment: thanks lc. After adding location and size, all controls are visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lc's comment resolved the issue. Thanks lc.

In the custom class,it was missed to initialize control's attributes "Location" and "Size". After initializing these attributes, the controls starts appearing in the form as expected.

```
public ref class CustomLine : public UserControl
{
private:
    Point P1,P2;
    Pen ^pen;
public:
    CustomLine(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        P1 = p1;
        P2 = p2;
        this->Location = P1;
        this->Size = System::Drawing::Size(Point(P2.X - P1.X, P2.Y - P1.Y));
        pen = gcnew Pen(Color::Red,2);
    }
protected:
    virtual void OnPaint(System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs ^e) override
    {
        e->Graphics->DrawLine(pen,P1,P2);
    }
};
```

Comment: It's great to answer your own question - in fact it's the right thing to do here. But for the next person that comes around, you should actually put *what the problem was* and *how you fixed it* in your answer.

Comment: please delete that answer